# Jquery Toggle working in IE/Chrome, Undefined in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seem to be having the opposite problem as everyone else, my Javascript isn't working in Firefox. Firebug is telling me the id is undefined, but it isn't, unless FF doesn't recognize  tags as objects to be controlled by javascript like IE/Chrome?

PHP Looks like this:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle(details_'.$record_details.')">Details</a>';  
echo '<tr style="display:none" id="details_'.$record_details.'">';
echo '<td class="noborder" colspan="7">';
echo '<div>';
   Bunch of Content Here.
echo '</div>';
echo </td>;
echo </tr>;
```

Javascript is just

```
function toggle(id){
$(id).toggle();}
```

The Sections toggle correctly in Both IE and Chrome, but Firefox returns "details_0 is not defined" etc. for every single one.

Any Suggestions? It's actually crashing at the call, weird enough because I put an Alert in the first line of toggle and it never fires, so it's not even making it that far. What am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: You should always look at what is in the browser source and not at your serverside code. It normally makes easier to spot your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it like this: `toggle(\'text in here\')`.

And in the toggle function call it like this: `$("#" + id).toggle();`.

Comment: tried it. didn't help. I thought so too, but that broke Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works at all is because some browser actually create window level variable `details_something`. So you are passing reference to your `tr` instead of string value its id.

Make sure value you pass to `toggle()` is enclosed in quotes. And make sure you prepend it with `#`